# ask $\mathfrak{M}_F$ in the construction of Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In Papa Rudin 2.14, under the section of construction of $\mu$ and $\mathfrak{M}$, it talks about $\mathfrak{M}_F$, which I don't understand.

It says let $\mathfrak{M}_F$ be the class of all $E \subset X$ which satisfy (two conditions): $\mu(E) < \infty$, and $\mu(E) = \sup \{ \mu(K): K \subset E, \text{K compact}  \}$. Finally, let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the class of all $E \subset X$ such that $E \cap K \in \mathfrak{M}_F$ for every compact K.

It's quite confusing for me to understand  $\mathfrak{M}_F$ and $E \cap K \in \mathfrak{M}_F$ .

I also don't understand the statement below from the textbook:

> $\mu(E) =0$ implies $E \in \mathfrak{M}_F$ and $E \in \mathfrak{M}$.
> Thus (e) holds, and so dos (c), by definition.

(e): If $E \in \mathfrak{M}$, $A \subset E$, and $\mu(E)=0$, then $A \in \mathfrak{M}$.

(c): For every $E \in \mathfrak{M}$, we have $\mu(E)= \inf \{ \mu(V): E \subset V, V \text{open}\}$

Comment: You can use \ in MathJax for almost anything; e.g. `$\sup$` gives $\sup$ a proper rendering, and `$\text{compact}$` renders your set properly with $\text{compact}$

Comment: If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, and $X\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ with the standard topology, then the class of $\mathfrak{M}_F$ that satisfies your set condition is in fact every Lebesgue measurable set of finite measure; as every Borel set (including compact ones) is measurable, and the intersection of measurable sets is measurable, $\mathfrak{M}$ includes all Lebesgue measurable sets of finite measure.

Comment: It would be good if you showed what (e) and (c) are in the book